# Custom background shapes for dialog in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, dialog, flutter-layout

I am trying to implement dialog which should have a custom card of some sort where the **child widgets can partially come out** as shown in this [sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nr61z.png)

Please help me how to recreate it in flutter.

Comment: try using a transparent background container, and inside this container, use Stack([a card for the content], [the tick image]).  I'm using mobile phone to type this comment, I hope you can understand what I mean.

Comment: I got what you said @KennethLi. It got tricky while doing, but I manage to write a [blog](https://medium.com/@excogitatr/custom-dialog-in-flutter-d00e0441f1d5) out of it. Kindly check it and correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: great work in your blog!  You may also want to wrap your showdialog inside another static function, say funShowDialog(strCaller, strTitle,strContent,listParms), so that you can call your showdialog in different widgets and show different titles/contents, and perform different actions according to strCaller.  You may save this funShowDialog in a separate dart file and Import this dart file in all other dart files that need to use showdialog.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will make those changes 

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest to use a dialog with container inside it  and then the container can have a column or stack and you can reposition your widget here is a little example

```
return Dialog(
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              overflow: Overflow.visible,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  child: Text('a widget'),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  child: Container( ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  child: Image.asset(
                    'your image link  here'
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: I tried doing this but did not work out well. But I managed to find the solution and wrote a blog on it. Please feel free to it checkout [here](https://medium.com/@excogitatr/custom-dialog-in-flutter-d00e0441f1d5) and correct me if am wrong.